# How to do PayPal Payflow Test Transactions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

I was trying to create Payflow Pro Sandbox account but i got to know that we have to use live account for testing. I created it by entering false credit card info but when i use false credit card information on click of 'Buy Now' Button it throws error "Credit card information is incorrect".

Can anybody help me in doing  credit card test transactions through Payflow.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need a "paid" Payflow account for testing. [Go here and select Payflow Pro](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/payflow-compare-pricing). Don't let the $99 set-up fee scare you away. You will be able to create the account without paying for testing purposes. You can submit test payments and see the transactions appear in your transaction history.  That way you can get your code working before taking the plunge in  activating your account for real live payments.

Comment: To add to this, the actual option for the test account is a few clicks into the process.  Look for the "I do not have a Processor. Setup test account." option on step 2.  Also, be sure to open (and read) the Gateway Agreement.

Comment: Hi James, Could you please help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843245/payflow-paypal-recurring-payment-expdate-validation

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure you have Live Payflow Pro credentials, you can simply submit your API calls to https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com instead of https://payflowpro.paypal.com

Note: As you mention 'Buy now button', I'd double-check your actually using Payflow Pro, since PayPal's standard buttons are referred to 'Buy now buttons' as well. For these, you **would** use the Sandbox at https://developer.paypal.com/ and https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yup! I was confused, excuse me as I am newbie. I have successfully done payflow test transaction now.
The purpose to create Payflow Pro account is I want to have some payments in my PayPal sandbox account done by Payflow Pro (basically payments done only by credit card not by any PayPal account ) as test cases.

I still fail to find out how to do it.
 
Any help provided is appreciable.

Comment: Hi Robert, Could you please help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843245/payflow-paypal-recurring-payment-expdate-validation