# How to create PayPal Payflow Pro test account

Tags: paypal

I need a PayPal Payflow Pro test account in order to create and test/use a WordPress plugin for payment with this method. I've done something similar for PayPal Website Payments Pro product and have set up testing in PayPal sandbox. The Payflow Pro product apparently doesn't work that way and PayPal documentation refers to vendors and partners as if it's necessary to have a live account in order to do testing.

An answer in this forum ([How to do PayPal Payflow Test Transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819424/how-to-do-paypal-payflow-test-transactions/14721225#14721225)) says it's possible "to create the account without paying for testing purposes" but when I go through that process I'm asked for payment information.

Can anyone point to information on how to set up a Payflow Pro test account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is surprisingly simple: when you're at the point that it's asking you for your payment information, simply close your tab / window.  The account will remain in a 'Test' state and you'll be able to use it for Payflow transaction testing.

(Yes, I'm aware that's hardly an intuitive way of setting up a test account. We're on it.)

Comment: Thanks, I stumbled upon that answer myself. Also somehow found PayPal info here: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://registration.paypal.com/welcomePage.do?mode=try .  This will sign you up for a trial account.