# Paypal Buy now button with single purchase only?

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have a shop with unique items (paintings) for sale so there can't be two purchases of a single item at the same time. But in case if two users will have a purchase page opened and finaly both of them will decide to do the Purchase the one who will be first will get it. Second will get the message that this item is already sold etc.

Is there any way to say to paypal that only one item_id can be sold ?

Of course it is possible to refund the second buyer his money, but less actions is always better.

**Also I understand in "Button Factory" you can easily specify the quantity of items you have, but can I specify this then using a HTML ?**

My HTML code for buttons is:

```
<form  name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="SELLER: 1, BUYER: 2">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="something@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Art work name 101">

<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="101">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.00">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Pay with PayPal - it's fast and secure!">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for your solutions or suggestions,
Max

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the maximum quantity available of a product when creating the pay now button in your PayPal dashboard.

The problem is also reported here and the how-to has been added as first reply:
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Settings-Archive/how-to-limit-the-number-of-items-being-sold-on-the-add-to-cart/td-p/445493

It is not possible to specify this trough HTML because this could be manipulated by end users. This wil result in order being sold multiple times but without enough stock.

Comment: This is not exactly what is needed. Of course you can limit qty in "Merchant Services" tools as you create the button manualy but in my case I can't aford to spend time on creating 1000 buttons or more. I just want to generate HTML buttons using PHP instead of copy-pasting them from PayPal Merchant Services.

Comment: As I noted, it seems not possible if I go trough the documentation and to me it makes perfect sense it is not possible because of security issues with this HTML approach. The HTML is out of your control and you don't want the end user to be in control of your payment process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403033/how-to-create-paypal-payflow-pro-test-account 

Maybe the paypal flow is the solution. I'm studding this moment.

Comment: Looks like a decent alternative. You also could look into a payment service provider, then it is also possible the add more payment options like credit card or so. This gives the customer more options to choose from and possibly more potential buyers!